# Where to install Burg?

Tags: software-installation, burg

I've seen a lot of guides to install Burg, but they all say do:

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda
```

And replace sda with whatever drive my boot information is on. When I do `sudo fdisk -l`, I get:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     3074047     1536000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *     3074048   358905658   177915805+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       604071936   625141759    10534912   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4       358905854   604071935   122583041    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       358905856   595953663   118523904   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       595955712   604071935     4058112   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So where should I do `burg-install` at? Am I just supposed to do it at `/dev/sda`? I really don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: How can I find out where grub is installed to? I just did a standard ubuntu 12.04 disk install where I click "install alongside windows 7" and move the slider. I haven't configured anything else at all.

Comment: I did the same thing. Did you go ahead and just use /dev/sda ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using grub installed to `/dev/sda`, then burg should be there too. I'm inclined to stay out of this question as far as answers go since you could be trying to chainload grub from the windows `boot.ini` and install a boot loader on `sda5` (although this requires forcing some things).

By default grub will install to `/dev/sda` and that's where you would install burg.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure before doing it. Burg looks really nice. :)

Comment: but /dev/sda isn't even listed up there! How can I verify that /dev/sda is where I should install it to as well?