# where is my Grub?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, partitioning, burg

Where is my GRUB located?? I want to install BURG now so i want to know where GRUB is.

This is my partition table.Plz help.

[image]

I tried [The boot info script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/files/latest/download) but cannot understand anything from its output..

The output is-

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
```

> ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================
>
> => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
>     the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
>      for (,msdos8)/boot/grub on this drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the software 'grub' is located in /dev/sda8

```
/boot/grub
```

For configuration see

```
/etc/default/grub
```

Probably grub is started in your master boot record of the harddisk /dev/sda

Comment: okay so what should i put in this command to install burg in place of grub    `sudo burg-install "(hd0)"`  instead of "(hd0)"??

Comment: @fossfreedom...okay so what should i put in this command to install burg in place of grub -`sudo burg-install "(hd0)"` instead of "(hd0)"??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141850/where-to-install-burg - so 'sudo burg-install /dev/sda'

Answer (score 0):

It depend, since you have a dual boot, and you likely have everything on master boot record ( mbr ).
Can you post the output of the bootinfo script, so we can look together ?

Comment: I pasted it just